# Python: Selenium getting empty results

Tags: python, selenium, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I am following [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DL7gyuqkzzU) to get myself familiar with selenium. My code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import os

chromedriver = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
os.environ['webdriver.chrome.driver'] = chromedriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800,600))
display.start()

br = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
br.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Now to print the results

```
q = br.find_element_by_name('q')
q.send_keys('python')
q.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
print br.title

results = br.find_elements_by_class_name('g')
print results

for result in results:
    print result.text
    print "-"*140
```

The output I am getting is just `python` and when I try to print `results` it is `[]`.

When I try the below code in chrome's javascript console it works fine.

```
res = document.getElementsByClassName('g')[0]
<li class=​"g">​…​</li>​
res.textContent
"           Python Programming Language – Official Websitewww.python.org/Cached - SimilarShareShared on Google+. View the post.You +1'd this publicly. UndoHome page for Python, an interpreted, interactive, object-oriented, extensible programming language. It provides an extraordinary combination of clarity and ...CPython - Documentation - IDEs - GuiProgramming"
```

So, any idea why am I not getting any results with selenium+python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `time.sleep(3)` after `q.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` seems to solve the problem. That's because when you press Keys.RETURN, ajax starts working and when you try to collect the result, they aren't on page yet. Selenium, AFAI has no stright way to determine whether the scripts like this have finished execution.

As I think, it would be more reliable to do

```
br.get("http://www.google.com/search?q=python")
results = br.find_elements_by_class_name('g')
```

Comment: +1. There is also the `WebDriverWait` method, where you can specify exactly which element to wait for. In this case, div ID `center_col` contains the results, and replacing the sleep with ` _ = WebDriverWait(br, 10).until(lambda x: br.find_element_by_id('center_col'))` (after you import via `from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait`). In any case, I vote for you!

Comment: i agree with RocketDonkey.  I think it's a bad idea to say that adding a time.sleep is the answer.  Please use WebDriverWait, or write your own polling ajax method.  There should be no case where a static sleep solves your problem